# optimizing short text comparisons

Tags: mysql

i have 2 tables `qs` and `local`. 
`qs` has 2 columns (actually built from several other columns) that are part of the comparison i need to do:

```
f1     | t1   
abcdaa | abcdbb
```

`local` just has one column that's part of the comparison:

```
rangeA
abcd
```

I am trying to find the entries in `qs` that do not have a matching substring in `local`

I've tried this in about a dozen different ways, and i must be missing something , since it's taking an unusual amount of time.

here is the fastest method I've found so far:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `tempB` SELECT f1, t1,
LEFT(f1,2) AS l2,LEFT(f1,3) AS l3,LEFT(f1,4) AS l4,LEFT(f1,5) AS l5,LEFT(f1,6) AS l6,LEFT(f1,7) AS l7,LEFT(f1,8) AS l8,
LEFT(f1,9) AS l9,LEFT(f1,10) AS l10,LEFT(f1,11) AS l11,LEFT(f1,12) AS l12,LEFT(f1,13) AS l13,
LEFT(t1,2) AS lt2,LEFT(t1,3) AS lt3,LEFT(t1,4) AS lt4,LEFT(t1,5) AS lt5,LEFT(t1,6) AS lt6,LEFT(t1,7) AS lt7,LEFT(t1,8) AS lt8,
LEFT(t1,9) AS lt9,LEFT(t1,10) AS lt10,LEFT(t1,11) AS lt11,LEFT(t1,12) AS lt12,LEFT(t1,13) AS lt13 FROM 
 (SELECT  CONCAT(c1,n1,s1) AS f1, CONCAT(c1,n1,s2) AS t1 FROM qs WHERE c1 ='a')tab0 ORDER BY f1 ASC;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `tempB2` SELECT rangeA FROM local WHERE rangeA LIKE 'a%' ORDER BY rangeA ASC;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `tempB3` SELECT rangeA AS rangeAA FROM local WHERE rangeA LIKE 'a%' ORDER BY rangeA ASC;

SELECT f1,t1, rangeA, rangeAA FROM tempB
LEFT JOIN tempB2 ON rangeA IN(l2,l3,l4,l5,l6,l7,l8,l9,l10,l11,l12,l13) 
LEFT JOIN tempB3 ON rangeAA IN(lt2,lt3,lt4,lt5,lt6,lt7,lt8,lt9,lt10,lt11,lt12,lt13) 
WHERE rangeA IS NULL OR rangeAA IS NULL
```

creating the temp tables is fast and starting with one character at a time (in this case 'a') significantly reduces the size of the datasets, but this is still very very slow even with only a few hundred thousand rows in each temp table.
I've tried using just f1 and t1 with a

```
 ON f1 LIKE CONCAT (rangeA,'%')
```

but that seemed to be even slower.

Any other ideas?

Note that rangeA is at least 2 characters long and at most 13 characters long. hence the LEFTs.

example data:

`qs` :

```
 c1  |  n1  | s1  | s2
 ab  | cd   | aa  | bb
 bb  | bbb  | bb  | bc
 cbc | cc   | cdd | ddd
 ddd | e    | ddf | def
```

`local` :

```
rangeA
abcd
bdddd
cbcccdd
dddedd
```

expected result:

```
  f1       | t1       | f1match | t1match
  bbbbbbb  | bbbbbbc  | NULL    | NULL
  cbccccdd | cbcccddd | NULL    | cbcccdd
  dddeddf  | dddedef  | dddedd  | NULL
```

Comment: i haven't looked your temp table,apart from that what result you need? i can understand tables you have mentioned

Comment: i don't understand your question. the result i need is the rows in `tempB` where f1 or t1 do not have a matching substring in the other table

Comment: still don't understand. once i have the values from `tempB` that don't have matching substrings in the `local`, i can easily use those values to find the rows in `qs`. the temp tables are just to save time and memory

Comment: temp table is your kind of approach.. what result set you need as a output.

Comment: "the result i need is the rows in tempB where f1 or t1 do not have a matching substring in the other table " example: f1 is bbbbbbb and t1 is bbbbbbc and there is no rangeA in `local` that is bbbbbbb or bbbbbb or bbbbb or bbbb or bbb or bb

Comment: @Bobert1234 A clear example would help. Show us a few rows in each table, and what you expect as the output. Don't describe it with temp tables, that's part of your solution, not the problem.

Comment: Have you got a data set ?  To confirm this is slow https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d6a88fa291e85f50386dd79f91dbcc27

Comment: Your query doesn't return the expected result. It is doing something that you nowhere describe in your problem statement. And it is anything but efficient, since you use two left joins on unindexed temp tables. So I would say - This "question" is unanswerable.

Comment: 1st, the result from the query are identical to the result from the sample query in the question, so incorrect that it wasn't described. second, indexing does not help on a table with a single column if you have to search against the whole table, which i do. as i mention below, it still doesn't work efficiently on larger datasets, and i'd be very pleased if someone has a better answer, i just haven't seen one yet

Comment: I get an [empty result](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4M2zKjyw9wFn5WBtLAS7JN/0) with your query.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you [Paul Spiegel for making this work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57356896/optimizing-short-text-comparisons/57401198#comment101284462_57401198).

---

Let's set up some test data.

```
mysql> select * from qs;
+----+---------------+-------------------+
| id | f1            | t1                |
+----+---------------+-------------------+
|  6 | match1        | no match          |
|  7 | match1        | match2            |
|  8 | foo match1    | match1 bar        |
|  9 | no match      | abc match2 123    |
| 10 | no match      | no match          |
| 11 | also no match | again not a match |
+----+---------------+-------------------+

mysql> select * from local;
+--------+
| rangeA |
+--------+
| match1 |
| match2 |
+--------+
```

And we expect only those rows which neither f1 nor t1 match any row in local.

```
+----+---------------+-------------------+
| id | f1            | t1                |
+----+---------------+-------------------+
| 10 | no match      | no match          |
| 11 | also no match | again not a match |
+----+---------------+-------------------+
```

---

***UPDATE***: Indexing `qs(f1,t1)` and `local(rangeA)` will help performance.

```
create index index_qs_fields on qs(f1,t1);
create index index_local_rangeA on local(rangeA);
```

[`instr`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_instr) finds a substring in a string, that simplifies many things.

We can do this with a [left excluding join](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/33052/%2fArticles%2f33052%2fVisual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins). That is to get only the rows on the left side (`qs`) which have no match on the right (`local`).

We do a normal left join to check for matches.

```
select qs.*, rangeA
from qs
left join local on 
    instr(f1,rangeA) or
    instr(t1,rangeA)

+----+---------------+-------------------+--------+
| id | f1            | t1                | rangeA |
+----+---------------+-------------------+--------+
|  1 | match1        | no match          | match1 |
|  2 | match1        | match2            | match1 |
|  3 | foo match1    | match1 bar        | match1 |
|  2 | match1        | match2            | match2 |
|  4 | no match      | abc match2 123    | match2 |
|  5 | no match      | no match          | NULL   |
|  6 | also no match | again not a match | NULL   |
+----+---------------+-------------------+--------+
```

And turn it into an excluding join by filtering for only those which don't match at all.

```
select qs.*, rangeA
from qs
left join local on 
    instr(f1,rangeA) or
    instr(t1,rangeA)
where rangeA is null

+----+---------------+-------------------+
| id | f1            | t1                |
+----+---------------+-------------------+
|  5 | no match      | no match          |
|  6 | also no match | again not a match |
+----+---------------+-------------------+
```

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a0e43f4952e3d4f71b77288e07810d8c)

---

***UPDATE***: Lots of entries in `local` can make this slow. We can try optimizing it by joining all the matches together into one regular expression. This *might* be faster.

We can construct our regex using [`group_concat`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)ing all the matches together as a single regex.

```
select group_concat(rangeA separator '|')
into @range_re
from local;

select qs.*
from qs
where not f1 regexp(@range_re) and not t1 regexp(@range_re);
```

Note that you'll need to be careful to escape regex characters in your matches.

---

Original way too complicated answer follows.

<strike>That tells us which entries in `qs` *don't* match entries in `local`.</strike>

```
select qs.id, f1, t1, rangeA
from qs
left join local on 1=1
where instr(f1,rangeA) = 0 and instr(t1,rangeA) = 0;

+----+---------------+-------------------+--------+
| id | f1            | t1                | rangeA |
+----+---------------+-------------------+--------+
|  6 | match1        | no match          | match2 |
|  8 | foo match1    | match1 bar        | match2 |
|  9 | no match      | abc match2 123    | match1 |
| 10 | no match      | no match          | match1 |
| 10 | no match      | no match          | match2 |
| 11 | also no match | again not a match | match1 |
| 11 | also no match | again not a match | match2 |
+----+---------------+-------------------+--------+
```

But we want those which don't match *all* of `local`. We can do that by counting up how many times a row appears in our list of not matches.

```
select qs.id, f1, t1, count(id)
from qs
left join local on 1=1
where instr(f1,rangeA) = 0
  and instr(t1,rangeA) = 0
group by qs.id;

+----+---------------+-------------------+-----------+
| id | f1            | t1                | count(id) |
+----+---------------+-------------------+-----------+
|  6 | match1        | no match          |         1 |
|  8 | foo match1    | match1 bar        |         1 |
|  9 | no match      | abc match2 123    |         1 |
| 10 | no match      | no match          |         2 |
| 11 | also no match | again not a match |         2 |
+----+---------------+-------------------+-----------+
```

And then select only those whose count is the same as the number of matches.

```
mysql> select qs.id, f1, t1
from qs     
left join local on 1=1     
where instr(f1,rangeA) = 0 
  and instr(t1,rangeA) = 0 
group by qs.id 
having count(id) = (select count(*) from local);

+----+---------------+-------------------+
| id | f1            | t1                |
+----+---------------+-------------------+
| 10 | no match      | no match          |
| 11 | also no match | again not a match |
+----+---------------+-------------------+
```

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ab33951b79b2b01aba4314da7cfd6a6a)

Comment: Wouldn't a NOT EXISTS condition or an ["anti-join"](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=61dbf6f0b306b8a5cad153a5f3e00ed7) be a bit simpler?

Comment: @PaulSpiegel Ahh! I couldn't get the left excluding join to work; I was using `and`. Very good. You should post that as an answer.

Comment: I'm fine if you post that. You did the most work creating the sample data. I just changed some bytes :-)

Comment: is INSTR faster than LIKE?? i'll give it a try, but i highly doubt this is better than the solution i already said was too slow in the question

Comment: @Bobert1234 I doubt `instr` vs `like` will make a difference, but try it. You don't give an idea of the size of `qs` and `local`, but if there's a lot of entries in `local` you might be able to speed things up by concatenating them together into a single regexp, I'd added that in to the answer. My guess is it's slow because it must do a full table scan for a substring search. [Postgres has GIN indexes for substring searches](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-types.html), AFAIK MySQL has no equivalent.

Comment: @Bobert1234 I assume `qs(f1,t1)` and `local(rangeA)` are indexed?

Comment: as i mentioned in the question,each temp table will typically have a few hundred thousand rows. as i also mentioned in the question, f1 and t1 are concatenated values built from `qs`, and so they are of course not indexed. i could potentially index them in the temp table, but i doubt that would help; as you said, nothing like a GIN index in MySQL

Comment: @Bobert1234 With all these temp tables and concatenated values, I feel like we're trying to optimize your solution, but not the original problem. If we saw your the original tables you're working from, and explained what you're trying to achieve, we might be able to work up a better solution. And there is a MySQL full text index which might be useful.

Comment: i added sample data

Comment: @Bobert1234 Thanks. [Making f1 and t1 into generated columns and indexing them might help](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/generated-column-index-optimizations.html), `f1 varchar(255) as (concat(c1,n1)) stored, t1 varchar(255) as (concat(n1,s1)) stored, index(f1,t1)`, but there's still that substring indexing problem. Full text search might work, `match(f1,t1) against(rangeA)`, but it wants a string, not a column.

Comment: i'd rather not mess with the existing table. i could create a new table with those columns and index, but i'm still not sure why that's better than using temp tables or even why you think an index would help. it needs to compare every line

Comment: i did some testing. unsurprisingly, adding indexes made no real difference, but using INSTR() instead of IN() made it take about a third of the time for smaller data sets (~ 35,000 rows), so thanks for that. i'm not sure if that's because it reduces the number of comparisons or if it's because it reduces the memory needed for the first temp table. my guess is the former. either way, i still can't handle larger datasets (>100,000 rows) in reasonable amount of time

Answer (score 0):

here's what i have so far, which works pretty well for <50k rows. Thank you to Schwern for the helpful discussion about INSTR().

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `tempB` SELECT f1, t1 FROM 
 (SELECT  LEFT(CONCAT(c1,n1,s1),17) AS f1, LEFT(CONCAT(c1,n1,s2),17) AS t1 FROM qs WHERE c1 ='a')tab0 ORDER BY f1 ASC;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `tempB2` SELECT rangeA FROM local WHERE rangeA LIKE 'a%' ORDER BY rangeA ASC;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `tempB3` SELECT rangeA AS rangeAA FROM local WHERE rangeA LIKE 'a%' ORDER BY rangeA ASC;

SELECT f1,t1, rangeA, rangeAA FROM tempB
LEFT JOIN tempB2 ON INSTR(f1,rangeA) =1
LEFT JOIN tempB3 ON INSTR(t1,rangeAA) =1
WHERE rangeA IS NULL OR rangeAA IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understand your question, I think you should look into using LOCATE() or POSITION(). I don't really get the need to using all those LEFT().

A overly simplified version of what I think you want is this:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `tempB` 
SELECT  CONCAT(c1,n1,s1) AS f1, CONCAT(c1,n1,s2) AS t1 FROM qs  ORDER BY f1 ASC;

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `tempB2` SELECT rangeA FROM local ;


SELECT tempB.f1, tempB.t1
from tempB
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) from tempB2 
WHERE POSITION(rangeA IN tempB.f1) != 0 AND POSITION(rangeA IN tempB.t1) != 0) = 0;
```